# WordPress DB error: Multiple primary key defined

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-error-1068

When I try to activate my custom plugin, I receive the error below:

> WordPress database error Multiple primary key defined for query ALTER TABLE temp CHANGE COLUMN `id` id int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY

```
private function runDbMigration_20() {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . PREFIX . "subscribers (
    id int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
    name tinytext NOT NULL,
    email text NOT NULL,
            secretkey text NOT NULL,
            random_key text NOT NULL,
            onehourmailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            onedaymailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            wbstartingmailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            replaymailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            temp_id int(11) NOT NULL,
            exact_time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
            watch_day varchar(3),
            watch_time time,
            time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
            last_seen datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
            active int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
            high_five int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            attended int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)" . $this->CHARSET_COLLATE . ";";
    return $this->calldbDelta($sql);
}
```

Please, can some one help me how to resolve this error?

Comment: The problem isn't occurring in the code you quoted. The problem appears to be with an "ALTER TABLE" (not "CREATE TABLE") and with a TEMPORARY table (not a permanent one). Does your MySQL server log queries and/or can you find where in the code ALTER TABLE is called on a temp table?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I will enable log queries on MYSQL server and will find the path where the ALTER TABLE code is lying @barrycarter

Answer (score 1):

Adding **PRIMARY KEY  (id)** at last resolved the error

```
private function runDbMigration_20() {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . WSWEB_DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "subscribers (
    id int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,     
    name tinytext NOT NULL,
    email text NOT NULL,
            secretkey text NOT NULL,
            random_key text NOT NULL,
            onehourmailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            onedaymailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            wbstartingmailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            replaymailsent int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    temp_id int(11) NOT NULL,
            exact_time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
            watch_day varchar(3),
            watch_time time,
            time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
            last_seen datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
            active int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
            high_five int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            attended int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)" . $this->CHARSET_COLLATE . ";";
    return $this->calldbDelta($sql);
}
```